# load css in CodeIgniter?

Tags: css, codeigniter

Currently I am using **CodeIgniter_2.1.3** and my problem is my **css** file is not work, but i think it load well because when I view the source code and click the following **href** link it help me to view the **css** file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
   href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter/_css/style.css"   
   media="screan" charset="UTF-8" title="no title" />
```

I keep my css file in **CodeIgniter/_css** directory and I use the following code ::

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="<?php echo base_url('_css/style.css');?>"   
   media="screan" charset="UTF-8" title="no title" />
```

I also use the following but no effect.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="<?php echo base_url();?>_css/style.css"   
   media="screan" charset="UTF-8" title="no title" />
```

Comment: yes, you are write, It works very well, many many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have loaded URL helper :

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Inspect using firebug or other web development tools for browsers if valid link has been printed on your link href.

If everything seems fine, then refresh the page. Ctrl + F5 which fetches the file from server again.

[URL Helper: Codeigniter Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is that localhost address what you're using? That's only going to work if you're running the browser on your server . . . spelling screen correctly would help as well.